# How to fix C++ compiler-error "cannot convert 'Type' to 'const Type*'"?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, compiler-errors

This is the complete error message:

> error: cannot convert 'MyTime' to 'const MyTime*' for argument '1' to 'int DetermineElapsedTime(const MyTime*, const MyTime*)'|

And this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;
struct MyTime { int hours, minutes, seconds; };
int DetermineElapsedTime(const MyTime *t1, const MyTime *t2);
const int hourSeconds = 3600;
const int minSeconds = 60;

int DetermineElapsedTime(const MyTime *t1, const MyTime *t2)
{
    long timeDiff = ((((t2->hours * hourSeconds) + (t2->minutes * minSeconds) + t2->seconds) -
                   ((t1->hours * hourSeconds) + (t1->minutes * minSeconds) + t1->seconds)));
    return(timeDiff);
}


int main(void)
{
    char delim1, delim2;
    MyTime tm, tm2;
    cout << "Input two formats for the time. Separate each with a space. Ex: hr:min:sec\n";
    cin >> tm.hours >> delim1 >> tm.minutes >> delim2 >> tm.seconds;
    cin >> tm2.hours >> delim1 >> tm2.minutes >> delim2 >> tm2.seconds;

    DetermineElapsedTime(tm, tm2);

    return 0;

}
```

Is there any way that I can fix? Please feel free to point out any other errors that you see. I do know about fixing DetermineTimeElapsed to properly output the hr:min:sec format. but right now I need  to get past this.

Comment: DetermineElapsedTime(tm, tm2); expects pointers

Comment: Hmm. Ok I see. So I change DetermineElapsedTime(tm, tm2); to DetermineElapsedTime(&tm, &tm2); Anyway who is down voting, what is wrong with the question?

Comment: @user1781382 Perfectly good questions get down voted without explanation all the time. Your question looks better than average to me. Maybe the note of panic in the question title? This isn't a major issue, for SO at least.

Comment: Thank you for being reasonable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error should be at below line:

```
DetermineElapsedTime(tm, tm2);
```

You are passing `MyTime` objects to the above function when it expects `const MyTime*`.

Fix it by either passing the object addresses:

```
DetermineElapsedTime(&tm, &tm2);
```

**Or better C++ way**: by changing the function prototype to accept object references:

```
int DetermineElapsedTime(const MyTime &t1, const MyTime &t2);
```

the body also will change accordingly; e.g. `->` will be replaced by `.` operator and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The function is expecting a pointer to 2 variables but you are passing the variables themselves, that is the issue. You fix this by passing a pointer to the variables by just passing their memory addresses using the `&` operator as shown below

```
DetermineElapsedTime(&tm, &tm2);
```

Alternatively you can change the function to receive references to the variables as @iammilind suggests, which would mean you can leave the above line as it was. This would be a safer, cleaner more "C++" way.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `DetermineElapsedTime` expects pointers to `MyTime`.

Change your code to:

```
DetermineElapsedTime(&tm, &tm2);
```

The `&` operator in this context means "get the address of"

Answer (score 1):

Your funciton needs to take two const pointers:

```
int DetermineElapsedTime(const MyTime *t1, const MyTime *t2)
                         \_____one______/  \______two_____/
```

Now, here's how you are calling it:

```
MyTime tm, tm2;
DetermineElapsedTime(tm, tm2);
```

As you see you are passing the variables by value instead of passing them by a pointer as a function would expect. You can fix it in a couple of ways:

- change the function to expect a const reference:

  ```
  int DetermineElapsedTime(const MyTime &t1, const MyTime &t2)
  ```
- take the address of the variables that are being passed:

  ```
  MyTime tm, tm2;
  DetermineElapsedTime(&tm, &tm2);
  ```
- allocate stuff dynamically and pass pointers:

  ```
  MyTime *tm = new MyTime();
  MyTime *tm2 = new MyTime();
  DetermineElapsedTime(tm, tm2);
  ```

Comment: Dynamic allocation might be an overkill for such problems.